# Trying to code Graph in c++, getting bad_alloc some of the time

Tags: c++, csv, memory, allocation, bad-alloc

I'm new to c++ after learning basic Object Oriented Programming in Java so I'm having a difficult time grasping memory deallocation. The assignment was to create a Weighted Directed Graph...

I'm getting the error: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc" when I run certain inputs through my code, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out what is causing it.

I googled the error and found that it was a memory problem, so I attempted to go through my code and try to find any leaks, but I am not sure where they are. Most posts are talking about pointers, which I do not tend to implement because I am unfamiliar with them. Thank you for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class WDGraph {
    private:
        map<string,map<string,int>> edges;
        vector<string> verts;
        list<string> leaves;
        list<string> roots;
        list<string> selfEdges;
    public:
        list<string> getRoots() { return roots; }
        list<string> getLeaves() { return leaves; }

        void addVert(string key) {
            verts.push_back(key);
        }

        void link(string start, string dest, int cost) {
            edges[start].insert(make_pair(dest,cost));
            if (!containsLeaf(dest) && !containsVert(dest)) 
                leaves.push_back(dest);
            if (!containsRoot(start) && !containsVert(start)) 
                roots.push_back(start);
            if (start == dest)
                    selfEdges.push_back(start);
            roots.remove(dest);
            leaves.remove(start);
        }

        bool containsVert(string key) {
            for (int i=0; i < verts.size(); i++) {
                if (key == verts[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool containsRoot(string key) {
            bool found = (find(roots.begin(), roots.end(), key) != roots.end());
            return found;
        }

        bool containsLeaf(string key) {
            bool found = (find(leaves.begin(), leaves.end(), key) != leaves.end());
            return found;
        }

        WDGraph() { }
        void printWDG() { 
            cout << "Printing Weighted Directed Graph." << endl;
            for (auto itr1 = edges.begin(); itr1 != edges.end(); ++itr1) {
                for (auto itr2 = itr1->second.begin(); itr2 != itr1->second.end(); ++itr2) {
                    if (itr2->first == "null" && containsRoot(itr1->first)) {
                        cout << "[" << itr1->first << "]";
                    }
                    else if (itr2->first != "null")
                        cout << "[" << itr1->first << " -> ";
                        cout << itr2->first << ", " << itr2->second << "] ";
                } 
                cout << "" << endl;
            }            
        }

        void printNumVerts() { 
            cout << "Total number of vertices: " << verts.size() << endl;
        }

        void printRoots() { 
            int num_roots = 0;
            cout << "Vertices with zero inbound edges: " << endl;
            for (auto itr = roots.begin(); itr != roots.end(); ++itr) { 
                cout << "[" << *itr << "]" << endl;
                num_roots++;
            }
            if (num_roots == 0) cout << "None" << endl;
        }

        void printLeaves() { 
            int num_leaves = 0;
            cout << "Vertices with zero outbound edges:" << endl;
            for (auto itr = leaves.begin(); itr != leaves.end(); ++itr) {
                if (*itr != "null")
                    cout << "[" << *itr << "]" << endl;
                    num_leaves++;
            }
            if (num_leaves == 0) cout << "None" << endl;
        }

        void printSelfEdges() {
            cout << "Vertices with self edges:" << endl;
            for (auto itr = selfEdges.begin(); itr != selfEdges.end(); ++itr) {
                cout << "[" << *itr << "]" << endl;
            }
        }    
};

int main() {
    WDGraph myWDG;
    string filePath;
    string line;
    int weight;
    size_t commaPos;
    vector<string> sVector;
    ifstream dataFile;

    // cout << "Please enter the relative path to an input file." << endl;
    // getline (cin, filePath);
    // cout << "The file path you entered was " << filePath << endl;
    // dataFile.open(filePath);

    dataFile.open("input.csv"); //test input

    while (getline (dataFile, line)) {
        commaPos = line.find(',');

        //Parse input file into string vector
        while (line.length() >= 1) { 
            if (line.length() == 1) {
                sVector.push_back(line);
                break;
            }

            sVector.push_back(line.substr(0,commaPos));
            line = line.substr(commaPos+1);
            commaPos = line.find(',');   
        }

        //Create vertices depending on number of parameters
        if (sVector.size() == 1) {            
            if (!myWDG.containsVert(sVector[0])) {
                myWDG.addVert(sVector[0]);\
            } 
            myWDG.link(sVector[0], "null", 0);
        }

        if (sVector.size() == 3) {
            if (!myWDG.containsVert(sVector[0])) {
                myWDG.addVert(sVector[0]);
            } 
            if (!myWDG.containsVert(sVector[1])) {
                myWDG.addVert(sVector[1]);
            } 

            weight = stoi(sVector[2]);
            myWDG.link(sVector[0], sVector[1], weight);
        }
        sVector.clear();
    }

    myWDG.printWDG();
    myWDG.printNumVerts();
    myWDG.printRoots();
    myWDG.printLeaves();
    myWDG.printSelfEdges();
}
```

When my .csv has simple stuff it works as expected, for example:

```
a,b,1
c,d,2
e
f,f,3
```

However, if I have stuff like this I get the error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc':

```
Hello
World,Hello,3
My,Name,4
Is
Nikki,Hello,3
```

Comment: did you tried debugging? you will get the line where the problem occurs

Comment: Leaks are annoying but don't cause a `bad_alloc` directly. `bad_alloc` happens when a memory allocation fails. One reason might be that memory is exhausted but nowadays this would mean rather huge memory consumption. Another cause might be that the requested size is unrealistically high. This might simply happen when size is provided by a variable which lacks proper initialization. So, it provides random values which might accidentally be sufficient or not. In general, usage of uninitialized variables is good for sporadic errors of any kind.

Comment: I would check that you have the line parsing code correct as it could end up looping forever and run out of memory as it adds the same string over and over.

Comment: @Nicole - could you please consider adding extra tags such as "csv"  and "string-parsing" to your question ? This is because bad_alloc was a symptom not a root cause of your problem. Adding the extra tags would make it easier for other users to locate the question; thanks ! We look forward to your future contributions to stackoverflow.

Comment: @jpmarinier Yes, of course! Sorry it limited me to 5 and I wasn't sure what tags were most relevant. Thank you for the tip!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Z E Nir, your line parsing code fails to consume any input if there is no comma "," in the line. You can of course debug your line parsing code, as debugging is a valuable skill to develop anyway.

However, a possible alternative to debugging consists in finding an existing C++ language construct that does what you want to do, and is part of the language library so it is already debugged.

Quite often, what you want to do is "*common stuff*", so debugging manual code will take more time than finding the appropriate pre-existing language construct, courtesy of your favorite internet search engine and/or stackoverflow itself. And being able to quickly find the language construct is also a very valuable skill.

In your case, function *getline()* takes an optional delimiter, which is a newline by default, but you can instead have  "," as delimiter and so use getline() again, but to parse a single line. It just takes a string object pretending to be a file stream, that is an std::istringstream object.

So you end up with two nested loops, both using getline():

```
    #include  <sstream>

    while (getline (dataFile, line)) {

        std::istringstream  iss{line};
        std::string         token;

        while (getline (iss, token, ',')) {
            std::cout << "DEBUG  TOKEN  LEN=" << token.length() << std::endl;
            sVector.push_back(token);
        }

        // go build myWDG
    }
```

That way, you don't have to mess up with lowly details such as the value of your commaPos variable. And the resulting code is easier to understand for another programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Heads up: Sorry for the style, but you really have to learn solving those kind of problem on your own. It's called debugging. I'm experienced programmer and yet, my code never run exactly as I thought it will when testing it in the first time. You need to learn how to use a debugger like `gdb` or the built in debugger in the `Visual C++` environment.

Now about your question:
The following code received the variable `line` with value `Hello`. There is no `,` character in `line` hence `line = line.substr(commaPos + 1);` return `Hello` all the time, and since 'Hello' string holds more then one character, you stuck in an infinte loop.

```
//Parse input file into string vector
        while (line.length() >= 1) { 
            if (line.length() == 1) {
                sVector.push_back(line);
                break;
            }   
            sVector.push_back(line.substr(0, commaPos));
            line = line.substr(commaPos + 1);
            commaPos = line.find(',');
        }
```

The problem isn't stop there. Since each iteration over the infinite loop your program executing: `sVector.push_back(line.substr(0, commaPos));` you actually allocates more and more memory, till you system won't give any more to this process. That's where you get the `bad_alloc` exception.
In other words, your error is not about `C++`, but about poor programing.

Reconsider your program, and think how you want to handle edge-cases like the `Hello`.
Oh, and never build objects on the stack. I know some places claim its OK to do this in the `main` function, but belive me its causing a lot of troubles.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I will definitely work on properly utilizing the debugger. I apologise for not doing that before asking on here.